# Error from ARM-assembly instruction 'MULS' with constant

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to execute

```
MULS r1, r1, #4
```

and get the follwing error when I use a constant value like `#4` as the third operand.

> error: A1647E: Bad register name symbol, expected Integer register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mul requires 3 registers as operands, so immediate values are not allowed. In this case you could use a mov that shifts left 2 bits:

movs r1,r1,lsl #2

Comment: muls also means to set the condition codes, otherwise it's the same as mul, multiply with 32 bit product (signed or unsigned result is the same with only 32 bit product). umull and smull are unsigned and signed multiply with 64 bit product.